# Find output of recursive method

Tags: java

I have to find the output, base case, recursive case, and depth of recursion of this method.
I can't figure out how to find the output.
This is the given method:

```
public int m5(int n){       //use n = 6 for initial n
         if(n>=3){
                n += m5(n-3);
                n += m5(n/2);
         }
         return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm does not converge. You can compute by hand the first 6 values of `m5(x)` which are:

```
x  m5
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   4
4   7
5  11
6  21
```

But now take a look at the computation of `m5(7)` you will have to compute `md5(7-3) = md5(4) = 7`. Then after the sum `n` is `7 + 7 = 14`. So in the next call you have to compute `md5(14/2) = md5(7)` but `m5(7)` is exactly what we are trying to compute so you have an infinity recursion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but how did you get the values of m5.